# iOS App terminating after upgrading POD 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'. Crash log says - "GADMediaContent setDelegate" unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, admob, cocoapods, google-mobile-ads

For the long time I was using "pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' 7.32.0". But now I must have to upgrade this, but found following crash, 
Crash log says - "GADMediaContent setDelegate"  unrecognized selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inside structure of **GADUnifiedNativeAd** in the latest version of **Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK** is different than the version **7.32.0**. So you have to use the latest version in your main project and also in those embedded frameworks which are also containing **Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK**.